# Creating Runtime Environment

Tags: java, multithreading, blockchain

I'm trying to build blockchain system which supports smartcontract by extending the another blockchain framework which doesn't smartcontract. I'm implementing in Java.To make it possible we need to create Runtime Environment for executing smartcontract using java. Can anyone help me out on how to go about??

**I have an interface:**

```
public interface smartcode{
    public void insert(/*asset related arguments*/){}
}
```

Every user has to implement the above interface for writing their smartcontract. So many user will be inserting their details by implementing this interface at the same time. For this to happen I have to assign each user's insert request to a thread(in Java). We have to send the request code snippets to another java code where this insert codes have to be assigned to java threads.

> My question is how to assign this each user insert request(which is java code) to a Runnable task being executed by a thread??

Comment: What have you tried so far? What is stopping you from creating a runnable using your ```interface smartcode``` as a ```runnable/callable```? And executing it in a thread? Should it be a thread or can it be a ```task```?

Comment: smartcode interface has method insert(..) and whenever user implement this , how runnable can be created  ?